# Replicate mysql database without root access to my.conf file?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, shared-hosting

I'm trying to find a way to replicate data from a remote **shared server**, where i don't have **root access**, to a local server, to maintain a offline access. Is there any option to do it?
I'm using **innodb** storage engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need root access to enable binary logging if it's not already enabled. You can see if it's enabled by running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin'` for example.

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_bin       | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

Enabling binary logs also requires a restart of the MySQL server. Sorry, there's no way around that.

Once binary logging is enabled on the master, you need:

- A recent data dump from the master server, with the binary log coordinates (e.g. created with `mysqldump --master-data`). You can get this data dump without root access, but you just need [a few privileges](http://patrickv.info/wordpress/2013/04/privileges-necessary-for-mysqldump/) on all tables in all databases. Alternatively, an administrator could create the data dump for you.
- A MySQL user on the master that has the `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege, and allows connections from your local instance.

Restore the data dump to your local MySQL instance, and use `CHANGE MASTER` to configure replication from the master, using the replica user and the binlog coordinates associated with the data dump. Then `START SLAVE`.

More detailed instructions on configuring replication are found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: thank you for yor answer. Unfortunally the log bin value is off.

Comment: If the administrator won't turn on binary logging, then the best you can do is take backups periodically and restore them on your local instance.